# algorithm2e with 'ruled' but with caption underneath?

Tags: formatting

I would like to present an algorithm in my article.
For that I am using the `algorithm2e` package (and I have used it for many years).

I want to use the `ruled` option, i.e., I load the package like this:

```
\usepackage[ruled,noend,noline,slide]{algorithm2e}
```

Unfortunately, with the `ruled` option, the `algorithm2e` package puts the caption above the pseudo code.

However, I want the caption to appear underneath the pseudo-code, just like any other caption in figures or tables.

Does anybody know, what I need to change in the style file to make this possible?
Or can I achieve it with the help of the `float` package?
(Note that I still would like to have a kind of algorithmic environment like this

```
\begin{myalgorithm}[tb]
\If{...}
\caption{An algorithm}
\end{myalgorithm}
```

)
I am using the latest version, i.e., 4.01, of `algorithm2e.sty`.

Comment: -1 -- same question at c.t.t.: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/0d1e260355173e78#

Comment: Thanks for asking the question. In my document, the default setting put the caption below the algorithm which I didn;t like. After seeing this post i realized that using the 'ruled' option would put the caption above the algorithm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by defining a new environment which puts the caption `under` instead of the default `top`, and adjusting the vertical skip between a rule and the caption text:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[ruled,noend,noline,slide]{algorithm2e}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{Ualgorithm}[1][htpb]
  {\def\@algocf@post@ruled{\kern\interspacealgoruled\hrule  height\algoheightrule\kern3pt\relax}%
    \def\@algocf@capt@ruled{under}
    \begin{algorithm}[#1]}
  {\end{algorithm}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\If{$i<5$}{some action}
\caption{A ruled algorithm with caption above}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{Ualgorithm}
\If{$i<5$}{some action}
\caption{A ruled algorithm with caption below}
\end{Ualgorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Gabriel: That should be easy to fix: Modify `\newenvironment{Ualgorithm}[1][h]...\begin{algorithm}[#1]`. This will make the default float placement `h`, unless otherwise specified using (say) `\begin{Ualgorithm}[tb]...\end{Ualgorithm}`.

Comment: @Werner: I added the optional argument; however, some tests I did, showed that it was not really necessary. The environment, as it was, behaved like a float. Perhaps I didn't do enough tests...?

Comment: [`algorithm2e.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/algorithm2e.sty) defines the `algocf[*]` environment as `\newenvironment{algocf}{\@float{algocf}}{\end@float}` which may have a default that doesn't correspond to the OP's taste. The testing is subjective, of course, since you don't have a document resembling the OP's setup.

Comment: LaTeX issues a warning if the optional parameter to `Ualgorithm` is empty, substituting it to the default `htbp`. Perhaps specify this as the default `[htbp]` to avoid this warning.

Comment: @Werner: yes, but what I meant (perhaps I wasn't clear) is that the `Ualgorithm` environment (as it was initially defined without the optional argument) would receive (and obey) the optional argument for placement specifiers.

Comment: Wow, you're right! That's LaTeX magic. I didn't know that.

Comment: @Werner: Yes. I didn't expected that at first, but then I saw that it worked and decided to leave it without explicitly defining the optional argument. However, after Gabriel's comment (and yours) I decided to make the definition explicit, for clarity's sake.