# Algorithm as a figure (to include additional caption below the figure)

Tags: floats, captions, algorithms

I have an algorithm in latex, and I need to add an addition caption underneath the algorithm (just like in a figure at the bottom: "Figure 1: Whatever it is". I tried simply changing the `\begin{algorithm}` to `\begin{figure}`, this does put a caption below the algorithm, however, this also changes the layout of the algorithm, and I don't want that to happen. It is possible to remain the same layout, but somehow add an additional caption just like in `figure`?

This is my code:

```
\begin{algorithm}[t]
\caption{Ant Colony Algorithm}
\label{ACA}
\begin{algorithmic}
\STATE Set parameters, initialize pheromone trails
\WHILE{stopping condition not met}
\STATE construct ant paths
\STATE local search (optional)
\STATE update pheromone
\ENDWHILE
\STATE \textbf{output:} the ACO solution path
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Comment: Please take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27671/algorithm2e-with-ruled-but-with-caption-underneath

Comment: It is unclear, whether the algorithm object should have a separate counter or whether it should also be numbered as figure object.

Comment: I want the algorithm to look like the one I get by using the above code, and have underneath it "Figure ...: Some text", or if possible "Algorithm ...: Some text" in the style of a normal figure caption. (So not Ualgorithm)

Comment: But would it not mean that you get *two* captions per algorithm? Which one should be the real caption that appears in a List of Algorithms? Also, what don't you like about the `Ualgorithm` solution in the question Papiro linked to?

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. I need my algorithm to have a caption that is/looks the same as a standard figure-caption. While, however, not changing the layout of the algorithm given above.

Comment: If you to reply to someone in person, put a `@` in front of his/her name, like so: @Marjolein. That way, people get informed about your reply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `algorithm` float uses the `ruled` style of the float package, and this style can be changed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\fs@ruled{%
  \def\@fs@cfont{\rmfamily}%
  \let\@fs@capt\floatc@plain%
  \def\@fs@pre{\hrule height.8pt depth0pt \kern2pt}%% or use \def\@fs@pre{} to get rid of the top rule
  \def\@fs@post{\kern2pt\hrule\relax}%% or use \def\@fs@post{} to get rid of the last rule
  \def\@fs@mid{\kern2pt\hrule\kern2pt}%% or use \def\@fs@mid{} to get rid of the middle rule
  \let\@fs@iftopcapt\iffalse}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[t]
\caption{Ant Colony Algorithm}
\label{ACA}
\begin{algorithmic}
\STATE Set parameters, initialize pheromone trails
\WHILE{stopping condition not met}
\STATE construct ant paths
\STATE local search (optional)
\STATE update pheromone
\ENDWHILE
\STATE \textbf{output:} the ACO solution path
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

For reference:
\begin{table}[hb]
  \caption{Table caption}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample output]

If you want to get rid of the last line below the caption (which looks better to me), use `\def\@fs@post{}` as indicated in the code. Likewise, you can get rid of any of the rules, if you wish so.

Comment: One does not need the `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` hack, the `float` package offers `\floatstyle{plain}\restylefloat{algorithm}` for that purpose. Or to make this even shorter, simply use `\usepackage[plain]{algorithm}`, see `algorithm` package doc for details.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt Nope. `\restylefloat{algorithm}` and `\usepackage[plain]{algorithm}` do not give you the rules, and I am not sure which rules the OP wants. I thought the OP wants at least top and middle rule, so ...

Comment: Guess you are right. I must confess that this question still confuses me. But since the questioner has accepted your answer It was you who was on the right track.