# How to write vertical lines in algorithm

Tags: algorithm2e

Hello please help me with this one, cant put vertical lines even with algorithm2e, i have to make it till Saturday.

Thank you very much

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What you try so far? See first example in https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Algorithms, it is what you looking for!

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279655/algorithm2e-override-defaults