# Using a package with and without an option in latex

Tags: packages, package-options

I need to use a specific package in two different ways, once with an option and another time without that option. More specifically, I want to use `algpseudocode` package once with `[noend]` option and once without it for two algorithms in a document. As far as I read on the web, calling a package twice with different options is not possible. I could not find a clear answer to this problem. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I found a similar question: [algorithm2e - override defaults](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279655/algorithm2e-override-defaults) but it uses `algorithm2e` package while I am using `algorithm`.

Edit: The package I need to use with and without `[noend]` option is `algpseudocode` not `algorithm`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: `noend` option of `algorithm` just makes the `\caption` command produce **noend 1** instead of **Algorithm 1**  can you confirm that is the effect you are asking for here. (The option is unrelated to the `noend` option in `algorithm2e`

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noend]{algorithm}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  aa
\caption{zzz}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
`

Comment: You're probably referring to `algorithmic` or `algpseudocode` rather than to `algorithm`.

Comment: Yes, You are right. It was a mistake. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably referring to `algpseudocode` or `algorithmic`, rather than `algorithm`.

#### Package `algpseudocode`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\newcommand{\algorithmwithoutend}{%
  \algtext*{EndWhile}%
  \algtext*{EndFor}%
  \algtext*{EndLoop}%
  \algtext*{EndIf}%
  \algtext*{EndProcedure}%
  \algtext*{EndFunction}%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\algorithmwithoutend

\caption{Euclid’s algorithm without end tags}\label{euclidwithout}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\algorithmwithoutend
\Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The gcd of $a$ and $b$}
\State $r\gets a\bmod b$
\While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if $r$ is $0$}
      \State $a\gets b$
      \State $b\gets r$
      \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
   \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhilewithout}
   \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is $b$}
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}

\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}

\caption{Euclid’s algorithm with end tags}\label{euclidwith}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The gcd of $a$ and $b$}
\State $r\gets a\bmod b$
\While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if $r$ is $0$}
      \State $a\gets b$
      \State $b\gets r$
      \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
   \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhilewith}
   \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is $b$}
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}

\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Package `algorithmic`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\algorithmwithoutend}{%
  \renewcommand{\ENDIF}{\end{ALC@if}}%
  \renewcommand{\ENDFOR}{\end{ALC@for}}%
  \renewcommand{\ENDWHILE}{\end{ALC@whl}}%
  \renewcommand{\ENDLOOP}{\end{ALC@loop}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}

\caption{Example algorithm with end tags}

\begin{algorithmic}
\REQUIRE $n \geq 0$
\ENSURE $y = x^n$
\STATE $y \leftarrow 1$
\STATE $X \leftarrow x$
\STATE $N \leftarrow n$ \WHILE{$N \neq 0$}
\IF{$N$ is even}
\STATE $X \leftarrow X \times X$ \STATE $N \leftarrow N / 2$ \ELSE[$N$ is odd]
\STATE $y \leftarrow y \times X$ \STATE $N \leftarrow N - 1$ \ENDIF
\ENDWHILE
\end{algorithmic}

\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}

\caption{Example algorithm without end tags}

\begin{algorithmic}
\algorithmwithoutend
\REQUIRE $n \geq 0$
\ENSURE $y = x^n$
\STATE $y \leftarrow 1$
\STATE $X \leftarrow x$
\STATE $N \leftarrow n$ \WHILE{$N \neq 0$}
\IF{$N$ is even}
\STATE $X \leftarrow X \times X$ \STATE $N \leftarrow N / 2$ \ELSE[$N$ is odd]
\STATE $y \leftarrow y \times X$ \STATE $N \leftarrow N - 1$ \ENDIF
\ENDWHILE
\end{algorithmic}

\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can not load a package twice, but you can usually reproduce the effect of an option from within the document.

`algorithm` does not define a `noend` option but it is a declared option as the package defines a default option.

```
\newcommand{\ALG@name}{Algorithm}
\DeclareOption*{\edef\ALG@name{\CurrentOption}}
\floatname{algorithm}{\ALG@name}
```

So redefining `\ALG@name` after the package is loaded, and re-execuing `\floatname`
will undo the effect of the option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noend]{algorithm}
\begin{document}

% noend caption
\begin{algorithm}
  aa
\caption{zzz}
\end{algorithm}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\ALG@name{Algorithm}
\floatname{algorithm}{\ALG@name}
\makeatother

% Algorithm caption, as if the option had not been used
\begin{algorithm}
  bbb
\caption{zzz2}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]